# jQuery doesnt get loaded on first attempt

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, jhipster

I am using jHipster to develop my application (JAVA + Angular JS).

In my html i have the following code for jquery UI tabs.

When i launch my application and go to the respective page, i cant see the expected style and also clicking on the button doesn't work.

When i go back to previous page and come back to the same jquery loaded page, **it works this time.**

Why is it happening so??

**Note:** 
I have placed the style class and js file imports  in the same html file. If I am changing these entries to my index.html file, its not working in the second attempt though.

Tried including the script in a separate file also. Same result as above not working even in the second attempt.

Anyone please suggest me.

Also, if anyone worked on tabs in jhipster, please tell me how to do it.

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus.    Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa  lectus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <p>Morbi tilorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, tur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.  </p>
  </div>
 </div>

 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://jqueryui.com/resources/demos/style.css">
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

 <script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    alert('ready!!');
    $(function () {
        $("#tabs").tabs();
    });
});
 </script>
```

Comment: Have you got errors in yout console ?

Comment: no errors in the console mate

Comment: did you checked my updated answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try to move style and js in header tag.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Tabs - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="tabs">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div id="tabs-1">
        <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, vehicula tempus, commodo a, risus.    Curabitur nec arcu. Donec sollicitudin mi sit amet mauris. Nam elementum quam ullamcorper ante. Etiam aliquet massa  lectus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-2">
        <p>Morbi tilorem euismod felis, eu ornare leo nisi vel felis. Mauris consectetur tortor et purus.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-3">
        <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis. Duis id erat. Suspendisse potenti. Aliquam vulputate, tur lorem enim, pretium nec, feugiat nec, luctus a, lacus.  </p>
    </div>
 </div>


</body>
</html>
```

[image: Working like a charm]

Comment: dogan, I  have tried this by adding to the <head> tag  in index.html

Comment: Still getting same issue

Comment: I've updated complete html code. Copy and past it in your new file and you will see it will work like i show in image.

Answer (score 0):

As I already told, there was a simple way to do this  using angular bootstrap...

I have achieved using tabs in my application with the below code.

```
<uib-tabset active="activeJustified" justified="true">
    <uib-tab index="0" heading="Incharges">
    </uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="1" heading="News">
    </uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="2" heading="Meetings">
    </uib-tab>
    <uib-tab index="3" heading="Gallery">content</uib-tab>
</uib-tabset>
```

Answer (score -1):

You should not combine Angular and jQuery (it's an Angular anti pattern). 
If you really want to go this way, you need to move the tabs code to your Angular controller.

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $(function () {
    // angular template content loaded
    $("#tabs").tabs(); //anti pattern!!!
  });
}]);
```

Maybe you should think about building a custom tabs directive.

E.g. like here: https://thinkster.io/angular-tabs-directive

Cheers

Comment: This is a content for a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Stefan, Thanks but do you have any example for the way you told?

Comment: Yeah, but i can´t comment with less then 50 rep. And i also answered to his question: 'you need to move the tabs code to your Angular controller'

Comment: @SmartDeveloper I updated the answer, to get a bit more explicit